# Composer nested requirements log

Tags: composer-php

How can i make composer verbose, so that i get a report like that:

```
 Problem 1
    - package "foo/bar" requested the package "contao/core == 3.5.31.0" which could not be found.
```

To be clear, my current report look like

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package contao/core == 3.5.31.0 could not be found.
```

But which of my 100+ Requirements need this package?

Comment: Has the `composer.lock` been written? Then you could try to call `composer why contao/core`

Comment: ty! that solved my problem. Please write a answer so i can mark this topic as "solved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the `composer.lock` been written? Then you could try to call `composer why contao/core` to see which package required contao.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends-why-) for that command - using `--tree` gives you a tree of the dependency graph which might be interesting if it is a nested dependency